# place two divs next to each other and center if enough space

Tags: html, css

I want to center a random amount of divs that is next to each other, but if there is not  enough space for the last one it most not be in center. I want somwthing like that:

▢   ▢   ▢   ▢    (<-no more space, place div down now instead->)
▢   ▢ ▢     ▢ (<-again no more space, place div down now instead->)
▢

How can that be done? please show me so i understand how

Answer (score 2):

You could use a container width a fixed with and any type of elements inside it.
I've created a fiddle and you might take a look at Twitter Bootstrap Scaffolding.

Flux is mentioning flexbox, good point, I updated the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/661hktxf/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-items clearfix">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
      item item item item item item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container-items {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .container-items {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .container-items {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 1170px) {
  .container-items {
    width: 1100px;
  }
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this. E.g. by having a centered wrapper and left floated items in it.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for trying to help me. THis worked, but the problem my div width is going be fixed to 480, changeing 80px to 480 center only 1 div instead of more... also i will not know the screen size its random

Comment: @hansatesta Sorry but I don't understand what you actually want, what does this have to do with the screen width?

Comment: my divs width is 480px, the screen is 1440px in width so there should be 2 divs in center but instead it placing them under ech other when i changed 80px to 480

Comment: @hansatesta make the .wrapper width 1000px

Comment: That worked! just one small problem. If there anything inside the div when i resize the browser they dont go under ech other

Comment: @hansatesta - well, you didn't mention, that it has to be responssive. In your case, you simply change the width of the wrapper to % instead of fixed px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `float`or [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

CSS ***float*** example:
[demo](http://jsbin.com/jatabeloke/edit?html,css,output)

HTML

```
  <section class="center">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <footer class="clear"></footer>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

With ***flexbox*** you can center the section and remove the clearfix footer.

Example: [demo](http://jsbin.com/cupobem/edit?html,css,output)

CSS

```
section {
  width: 500px; 
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This does not center the elements as required in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic one I done... Easy on the eyes and easy to understand. If you want it responsive though it's a different story and you will need media queries. Change the height to a desired height or min-height. Take off background-color as it's there so you can see what it looks like.

```css
#wrapper {
  width:1440px;
}
.cols {
  width:20%;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:1.1%;
  background-color:#333;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="cols">1</div>
  <div class="cols">2</div>
  <div class="cols">3</div>
  <div class="cols">4</div>
  <div class="cols">5</div>
  <div class="cols">6</div>
  <div class="cols">7</div>
  <div class="cols">8</div>
  <div class="cols">9</div>
  <div class="cols">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the divs go under ech other if i resize the browser?

Comment: They won't. If you want them to resize though make sure that you change width to max-width where #wrapper is

Comment: By the way #wrapper is there to replicate your websites width so there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `display:table` and `margin:auto;` or `inline-table` ,  `inline-flex` , `inline-block` and text-align to center the wrapper.

`inline-block`, `inline-table`,`inline-flex` or `float` for the children.

Choices of `display` value depends on global behavior expected

here a few examples with various amount of boxes *(play the snippet in full page to see behavior on resizing window)*:

- table + float

```css
ul,

li {

  /* reset */

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

  display: block;

}

ul {

  display: table;
  margin: auto;

}

li {

  width: 75px;

  height: 75px;

  background: lightblue;

  margin: 5px;

  float: left;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<ul>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
  <li>item box</li>
</ul>
```

inline-flex + inline-block

```css
body {
  text-align:center;
}
ul, li {
  /*reset*/
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
}
ul {
  display:inline-flex;/* or inline-block or inline-table */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:center;
}
li {  
  width:78px;
  height:78px;
  background:lightblue;
  margin:5px;
  /* display:  inline-block; or float:left; or */
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<ul>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<ul>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
  <li> item box </li>
</ul>
```

you can switch displays for the wrapper  and display and float for children to use the method that suits best your needs for the children styling.

**The idea here is to have a wrapper that shrinks on content and center itself** (or is centered via text-align) and grow while content gets bigger. **No need to set a width on the wrapper these ways**